# iPhone fullscreen webapp without AJAX

Tags: iphone, ajax, web-applications

I'm building an iPhone webapp (using JQTouch at the moment). It's a fullscreen app, you know, the ones installed on the home screen without the Safari chrome. If you tap a normal link (without AJAX that is) the link opens in Safari, taking you out of the webapp.

**Is there a way to build non-AJAX webapps for iPhone?**

The problem is AJAX isn't always a feasible solution. I would like to implement OpenID for this particular webapp for example but it means you have to redirect to an OpenID provider which links back to your URL but... without AJAX off course...

PS: I know you can build "real" apps with PhoneGap (and others) and I even built native apps before but, to be honest, I'm tired of paying €70/year for building free apps (it's for a hobby project, nothing professionally).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can open OpenID links in iframe. OAuth, Facebook Connect, etc, all can work in that way.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the only solution. Still feels like an ugly hack though... :(

Comment: Facebook Connect works in this way. They make it like an in-page pop-up dialog. I think it's still okay. Implementation won't be easy, so you might want to use 3rd-party OAuth (or alike) implementation.